# Rails / Stripe - Payment won't process

Tags: javascript, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller, stripe-payments

I'm building an events app using Rails and Stripe to handle payments. I've set up a reserve method in my Booking model to handle the payments process.

The code must be able to allow a user to book more than one space at a time.

I'm not getting any errors, however, every time I try and process a booking of any kind I'm getting the error message 'Booking Unsuccessful' from my code. I can't seem to see why it is jumping straight to this rather than completing the payment and booking.

Here's the reserve method in my Booking Model -

```
    def reserve
    # Don't process this booking if it isn't valid
    return unless valid?

    # We can always set this, even for free events because their price will be 0.
    self.total_amount = quantity * event.price

    # Free events don't need to do anything special
    if event.is_free?
      save

    # Paid events should charge the customer's card
    else
      begin
        charge = Stripe::Charge.create(amount: total_amount, currency: "gbp", card: stripe_token, description: "Booking number #{Booking.id}", items: [{quantity: quantity}])
        self.stripe_charge_id = charge.id
        save
      rescue Stripe::CardError => e
        errors.add(:base, e.message)
        false
      end
     end 
  end
end
```

In my bookings_controller I have the following new and create actions -

```
    def new

        @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
        @booking = @event.bookings.new(quantity: params[:quantity])
        @booking.user = current_user

    end

    def create
    @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
    @booking = @event.bookings.new(booking_params)
    @booking.user = current_user

        if @booking.reserve
            flash[:success] = "Your place on our event has been booked"
            redirect_to event_path(@event)
        else
            flash[:error] = "Booking unsuccessful"
            render "new"
        end
    end


    private

    def booking_params
        params.require(:booking).permit(:stripe_token, :quantity)
    end
```

What is it that's causing @booking.reserve to fail and the code simply to default to the flash error message?

This is the code in my view. Do I need to add anything to my Stripe javascript code?

**booking.new.html.erb**

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3" id="eventshow">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h2>Confirm Your Booking</h2>
        </div>
                  <div class="calculate-total">
                              <p>
                                  Confirm number of spaces you wish to book here:
                                    <input type="number" placeholder="1"  min="1" value="1" class="num-spaces">
                              </p>
                                <p>
                                    Total Amount
                                    £<span class="total" data-unit-cost="<%= @event.price %>">0</span>
                                </p>
                          </div>





                <%= simple_form_for [@event, @booking], id: "new_booking" do |form| %>



                 <span class="payment-errors"></span>

                <div class="form-row">
                    <label>
                      <span>Card Number</span>
                      <input type="text" size="20" data-stripe="number"/>
                    </label>
                </div>

                <div class="form-row">
                  <label>
                  <span>CVC</span>
                  <input type="text" size="4" data-stripe="cvc"/>
                  </label>
                </div>

                <div class="form-row">
                    <label>
                        <span>Expiration (MM/YYYY)</span>
                        <input type="text" size="2" data-stripe="exp-month"/>
                    </label>
                    <span> / </span>
                    <input type="text" size="4" data-stripe="exp-year"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-footer">    

               <%= form.button :submit %>


            </div> 

<% end %>
<% end %>

      </div>
  </div>
</div>  

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.calculate-total input').on('keyup change', calculateBookingPrice);

function calculateBookingPrice() {
  var unitCost = parseFloat($('.calculate-total .total').data('unit-cost')),
      numSpaces = parseInt($('.calculate-total .num-spaces').val()),
      total = (numSpaces * unitCost).toFixed(2);

  if (isNaN(total)) {
    total = 0;
  }

  $('.calculate-total span.total').text(total);
}

  $(document).ready(calculateBookingPrice)

</script>



<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.stripe.com/v2/"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  Stripe.setPublishableKey('<%= STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY %>');
  var stripeResponseHandler = function(status, response) {
    var $form = $('#new_booking');

    if (response.error) {
    // Show the errors on the form
    $form.find('.payment-errors').text(response.error.message);
    $form.find('input[type=submit]').prop('disabled', false);
    } else {
    // token contains id, last4, and card type
    var token = response.id;
    // Insert the token into the form so it gets submitted to the server
    $form.append($('<input type="hidden" name="booking[stripe_token]"     />').val(token));
    // and submit
    $form.get(0).submit();
    }
  };

  // jQuery(function($)  { - changed to the line below
  $(document).on("ready page:load", function () {

    $('#new_booking').submit(function(event) {
      var $form = $(this);

      // Disable the submit button to prevent repeated clicks
      $form.find('input[type=submit]').prop('disabled', true);

      Stripe.card.createToken($form, stripeResponseHandler);

      // Prevent the form from submitting with the default action
      return false;
    });
  });
</script>
```

I'm wondering if the key line is this one?

```
  self.stripe_charge_id = charge.id
```

Do I need to add anything to my bookings table? Here's the schema -

```
create_table "bookings", force: :cascade do |t|
t.integer  "event_id"
t.integer  "user_id"
t.string   "stripe_token"
t.datetime "created_at",   null: false
t.datetime "updated_at",   null: false
t.integer  "quantity"
t.integer  "total_amount"
  end
```

I'm fairly new to Rails and this is the first time I've tried to implement a payment process like this. I'm sure to an experienced eye this may be straight forward. Any assistance would be appreciated.

**QUESTION UPDATE - 25/09/16**

I've done some work on my question and I've found that this line was stopping the entire 'reserve' method from proceeding (as it suggests it would) -

```
  # Don't process this booking if it isn't valid
    return unless valid?
```

I then ran into an 'undefined method '*' for nil:class' for this line -

```
 # We can always set this, even for free events because their price will be 0.
    self.total_amount = booking.quantity * event.price
```

So, I've commented out both those lines as I'm at a loss as to why they aren't working. I want to be able to at least get to a stage where I can process a payment but now I get this error -

[image: Stripe error - source or customer]

I'm pretty sure source is the correct option for my app and I've tried to add code for that but it's not taking it. What would be the right option?

Comment: You're passing `card: stripe_token` to `Stripe::Charge.create`. It should be `source: stripe_token`.

Comment: Tried that. Doesn't work - get same error.

Comment: What's the error message detail after you change it to `source`?

Comment: The exact same. It's not changing anything. Tried it in between "" and as self.stripe_token but still the same.

Answer (score 0):

In your bookings_controller::create action you are accessing an event using

```
@event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
```

I have checked new.html.erb, and I think you have not passed event id to create action. Please do check for it.

**Passing event_id using javascript:**

var eventID = "<%= @event.id %>"

Add above line in your view where you started javascript.

And

```
$form.append($('<input type="hidden" name="event_id">').val(eventID));
```

add this above line in $('#new_booking').submit function.

Comment: Where would I put that?

Comment: Add it in the form using hidden field. And then at controller action, check puts params, and puts @event.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: Try adding this <input type="hidden" name="event_id" value="<%= @event.id %>"> just before  <%= form.button : submit %> line.

Comment: Do I need to include event_id as part of booking_params also?

Comment: I've tried the above and I'm afraid that doesn't work.

Comment: Have you checked what parameters you get at create action ?

Comment: No. I'm not sure what that would solve? Have you had a similar issue to the one I describe above, before?

Comment: Whereabouts did you mean for the above line of code to go in my view form above? You need to be quite specific in your answer because I'm not sure whether you meant this as Ruby code or part of the stripe javascript code.

Comment: First of all I am trying to confirm that the issue is about event_id related, so I asked you to check for what params you are getting, If the issue is related to event_id, we will try other options too to pass it with the form.

Comment: Ah - okay. But when you're asking about the code above are you referring to the JavaScript or the ruby code on the view page?

Comment: okay, If you have checked the params and if issue is related to event_id then, please check the updated answer.

Comment: Okay, I'll try this but I'm just wondering if its better to try debugging.

Answer (score 0):

I see in your reserve model you do

```
 self.stripe_charge_id = charge.id
```

However you don't have that field as per your migration. So i'd suggest you create that field in your migration.

I'd also recommend using `save!` instead of `save` so that it throws an error which can be rescued by the rescue statement

```
 begin
   charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
     :amount => total_amount,
     :currency => "gbp",
     :source => stripe_token, # obtained with Stripe.js
     :description => "Booking created for amount #{total_amount}"
    )
   self.stripe_charge_id = charge.id
   save!
 rescue Stripe::CardError => e
   errors.add(:base, e.message)
   false
end
```

From your error, you are incorrectly calling the stripe API. You must provide a `source` argument which you do not. You can read more at https://stripe.com/docs/api/ruby#create_charge

Comment: So, I don't use stripe_token I use stripe_charge  ( what's the difference between the two)? When I add that to my bookings table what do i use as input type - string?

Comment: I've made the migration as above and it still doesn't process the payment.

Comment: Is this something as simple as a referencing issue for the reserve method in my Booking model? I have @booking.reserve in my create action in the controller but no reference to it anywhere else - does it need to be referenced in my new action also? Does it need to be referenced in my views so it gets called? Does my view page need to be named booking.create? Thinking this must be a simple thing but I'm missing it.

Comment: No, that would be very contrary to rails convections. Try debugging in your controller see the error. after `if @booking.reserve` in your controlker, put a debug statement `puts @booking.errors.inspect`. Let me know what that returns so I can figure out what is going on

Comment: I've done some work on this and its the first line - return unless valid? - that is blocking the rest of the code. How do I amend this so that the rest of the code can run?

Comment: You din't give me what the result of `puts @booking.errors.inspect` is...I can't be able to help without that. Looks like Your booking instance has some errors

Comment: Hi, I've been away from this the last 24 hours sorry for not coming back. If you look above I've provided a detailed question update at the bottom of the original question as to where I now stand. I hope this explains why I've not done the inspect task.

Comment: Am i barking up the wrong tree with all of this? I seem to be running into error after error here. Is there a better way of getting my app to complete this task? The key here is that I must have it accept payments for multiple reservations not just one whilst saving the booking. I'm open to any solution, I just want it to work.

Comment: @Mike.Whitehead i've updated my answer. The `Stripe::Charge` method needs a `source` argument which you are not providing as per the documentation https://stripe.com/docs/api/ruby#create_charge. Also no argument `items`

Comment: I'm now getting 'undefined method id for Booking.id',

Comment: I never looked into your code indepth you can't do `Booking.id`...`id` must be called on an instance of Booking but not on the class. The `id` is not available until the record is saved and since the description can be anything I just used a random string. Check out the updated answer

Comment: Okay, we've now gone back to the 'must provide source or customer' error. I'm not kidding. This is getting nuts now.

Comment: I had this code in my controller before moving to model on recommendation and never got any errors like this. Is it not better to try and save the booking before processing the payment?